# servicemix : jms message as persistent

Tags: jms, apache-servicemix

I am using ServiceMix 4.2. How can I set a JMS message as "persistent"?

Is it a property in `xbean.xml` or should I write code in `CustomMarshaller` to mark the JMS message as persistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sending a queue message, it will be persistent by default. 
Also see http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-disable-persistence.html.